# Make LaTeX compilation abort if bibitem is using

Tags: bibliographies

How to make LaTeX compilation abort if \bibitem is using? Below is a code snippet which I want the compilation to fail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,longtable,amsmath,booktabs,url,amstext,array,geometry}

\begin{document}
\cite{notes}
\cite{notes2}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History 21.479.}  1991.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you open to using BibLaTeX?

Comment: Till now I have only used PdfLatex, but no harm in trying a different compiler.

Comment: Heh, not quite :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/17423  BibLaTeX/`biber` is the next generation of BibTeX.

Comment: for a document of any size it is normal to _not_ write the `thebibliography` but let a separate program (bibtex or more recently biber) generate that based on information from the first run, in which case getting the `?` for _all_ citations on the first run is normal.

Comment: @SeanAllred - I guess the OP wants an error message to be issued if a `\bibitem` instruction is encountered in the tex file. This would seem to be independent of the issue of *how* the `\bibitem` instruction got there: somebody could have written it entirely by hand, or either bibtex or biblatex (with either bibtex or biber as the backend) were used to create the `\bibitem`s...

Comment: If `\bibitem` is using *what*?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments it is better to use bibtex or biber to generate the bibliography however latex warns at the end of document for any undefined citations or references and you can easily make that an error rather than a warning if you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,longtable,amsmath,booktabs,url,amstext,array,geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\G@refundefinedtrue{%
  \gdef\@refundefined{%
    \GenericError{}{}{There were undefined references}{you wanted an error}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{notes}
\cite{notes2}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History 21.479.}  1991.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

with the above, the terminal output shows:

```
! .

There were undefined references
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \end{document}

? h
you wanted an error
?
```